# How to unit-test a custom element, built with "compose"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I have a simple "factory" element that looks like as follows.

```
<template>
    <compose repeat.for="segment of segments" 
             view-model.bind="segment.ViewModelClass"
             model.bind="segment.Model"></compose>
</template>
```

I am trying to unit-test this component using something like the following.

```
let component: ComponentTester<MyFactory> = StageComponent.withResources("MyFactory/MyFactory");
component.inView("<my-factory segments.bind='segments'></my-factory>")
         .boundTo({ segments })
         .create(bootstrap)
         ....
```

However, when I do so, I get the following DI error.

> Error: Error invoking Compose. Check the inner error for details.
>
> Inner Error Stack:
>   Error: Constructor Parameter with index 0 cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?
>       at Object.invokeWithDynamicDependencies (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/aurelia-dependency-injection/dist/native-modules/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:449:13)...

One might say that I am testing a code (`compose`), which is not mine, and already unit-tested. But the problem is when I use `my-factory` custom element in `my-other-custom-element`, the mere usage of `my-factory` breaks all the test cases for `my-other-custom-element` due to the same error. The usage of `my-factory` looks as follows.

```
<template>
<require from="path/to/MyFactory"></require>
...
<my-factory segments.bind="segments"></my-factory>
...
</template>
```

This is the reason, I need to fix this error.

It seems that this error is due to the fact that the first ctor argument of `compose` is `DOM.Element`, which is initialized by `aurelia-pal`. And it seems that during initialization at the time of testing, there is some problem initializing `pal` correctly (and in correct order?). Is there any way to correct this situation? May be using manually handled lifecyle? However, as I am not really sure how to proceed, please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

It is now solved, the issue is because PLATFORM specific code to adjust reference to `Element` class was not run before all else. Related discussion https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/solved-how-to-test-a-view-with-a-named-slot/680/

The solution is to ensure real test code will only be ran after calling platform initialization if this is in application code. For Aurelia side, all injection declarations have been moved inside a static `inject()` function, so this won't happen again.